# Settings API - getting hidden input / submit button's name

Tags: validation, settings-api

I'm generating this form using Settings API:

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">   
   <?php settings_fields('XX_theme_settings'); do_settings_sections('my_settings'); ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
   <input name="SubmitButton" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes'); ?>" />   
</form>
```

Validation callbacks $input array returns only 'my_settings' input fields.

How do I access `foo` (`bar`) input's value and submit button's name `SubmitButton`?

This doesn't work for the hidden input:

```
my_validation($input) {
   $foo = $input['foo'];
}
```

And when it comes to the submit button I don't even know where to start.

Comment: and $foo = $_POST['foo']? I don't use settings API too often, just a guess.

Comment: Christ, I was trying to do everything within Settings API and didn't even tried $_POST array. Of course you were right, it works! Please repost your comment as an answer so I will be able to accept it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$_POST` is too low level. Simply give it the same name as your other options. When you options are displayed they should have the names of the form: `my_settings[a_particular_option]`. For instance:

```
<input name="my_settings[some_input_option]"/>
```

Then for your hidden input and submit button:

```
<input type="hiddden" name="my_settings[foo]" value="bar"/>
<input name="my_settings[SubmitButton]" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes'); ?>"/>
```

In your validation array

```
my_validation($input) {
   $foo = $input['foo'];
   $submit = $input['SubmitButton'];
}
```